# Exclude directories in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to exclude all directories from my search in PowerShell. Both `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` contain `Attributtes` property that seems to be exactly what I want, but I wasn't able to find out how to filter based on it. Both

```
ls | ? { $_.Attributes -ne 'Direcory' }
ls | ? { $_.Attributes -notcontains 'Direcory' }
```

didn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Side note: It'd be "Directory". Then both actually work for directories which do not have any other attributes set (such as ReparsePoint).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Such stupid mistake.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `PSIsContainer` property:

```
gci | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer }
```

Your approach would work as well, but would have to look like this:

```
gci | ? { !($_.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::Directory) }
```

as the attributes are an enum and a bitmask.

Or, for your other approach:

```
gci | ? { "$($_.Attributes)" -notmatch "Directory" }
```

This will cause the attributes to be converted to a string (which may look like "Directory, ReparsePoint"), and on a string you can use the `-notmatch` operator.

PowerShell v3 finally has a `-Directory` parameter on `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory
gci -ad
```

Comment: It seems just using LS isn't working?
**PS:D:\batch> (ls d:\batch -Recurse -File *.ps1).count
550**

Comment: ...though when I try to exclude a folder that fails
(ls d:\batch -Recurse -File *.ps1 -Exclude 'D:\batch\foldertoexclude\*.ps1').count
STILL shows 550
(The actual path of foldertoexclude posted is "D:\batch\foldertoexclude\*.ps1", but the form here removes the "\" before the '*.ps1' inside of single ' ...weird, right?...
Oh, wow, even inside double " LOL!
'D:\  batch  \  foldertoexclude  \  *.ps1'

Answer (score 11):

#### Exclude directories in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_ -isnot [IO.DirectoryInfo]}
```

Or it's terse, but harder to read version:

```
gci | ? {$_ -isnot [io.directoryinfo]}
```

Credit goes to @Joey for his insightful comment using the `-is` operator :)

#### However

Technically, I prefer *including* only Files or only Directories since excluding can lead to unexpected results as Get-ChildItem can return more than just files and directories :)

#### Include just Files:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_ -is [IO.FileInfo]}
```

Or:

```
gci | ? {$_ -is [io.fileinfo]}
```

#### Include just Directories:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_ -is [IO.DirectoryInfo]}
```

Or:

```
gci | ? {$_ -is [io.directoryinfo]}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also filter out directories by looking at their type directly:

```
ls | ?{$_.GetType() -ne [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]}
```

Directories are returned by get-childitem (or ls or dir) of type System.IO.DirectoryInfo, and files are of type System.IO.FileInfo. When using the types as literals in Powershell you need to put them in brackets.

Comment: You can use the `-is` operator to do this, by the way. So it can be shortened to: `gci | ? {$_ -is [IO.FileInfo]}`

Comment: Of course you are limited to the File System Provider with this method whereas PsIsContainer should work with any provider where the concept of containers exists.

Comment: Should have thought of the -is operator. And yes, FileInfo will only work for File Systems.

Answer (score 0):

Timings for different approaches, times of 5000 itarations on a short dir /  25 iterations on System32 dir. Measuring is done using:

```
(measure-command { for ($i=0;$i -lt 5e3;$i++) {       
  $files= gci | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer }   # this is target to measure
} } ).totalmilliseconds
```

Results from slowest to fastest (all lines have same end result):

```
$files= gi *.* | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer }  #5000 iterations / 25long = 15.2sec / 22s
$files= foreach ($file in gi *.*) { if ($file.mode -notmatch 'd') { $file } }   # 11.8s / 20s
$files= gci | ? { !($_.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::Directory) }  # 8.9s  /  10.7s
$files= Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.mode -notmatch 'd'}  # 8.8s  / 10.6s
$files= gci | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer }  # 7.8s  / 9.8s
$files= Get-ChildItem | ? {$_ -isnot [IO.DirectoryInfo]}  # 7.6s  /  9.6s
$files= gci | Where-Object {$_ -is [IO.FileInfo]}  # 7.6s  / 9.6s
$files= foreach ($file in gci *.*) { if ($file.mode -notmatch 'd') { $file } }    #7.3s  / 12.4s
$files= @( foreach ($file in gci) { if ($file.mode -notmatch 'd') { $file } } ) #3.7s  /  6.4s
$files= foreach ($file in gci) { if ($file.mode -notmatch 'd') { $file } }  # 3.7s  /  6.4s
```

Notice that specifying "*.*" will almost double process time. That's why GCI without parameters is fastest than GI which must use *.* parameter.